# Electronic Structure Calculation with External Field

Tags: density-functional-theory, software-recommendations, electronic-structure, one-topic-per-answer, hartree-fock

There are various programs for calculating energy states for molecules (ORCA, Gaussian, ...). Is there also software that allows the same simulations with an additional external potential (e.g. magnetic field)?

Comment: In this paper there are a few references to codes to compute the electronic structure under a magnetic field. (https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jctc.0c01297) I am not an expert so I am afraid this is the most that I can do

Comment: @capitn96 Thanks!